# Cisco L2TP Tunnel and NAT

Tags: cisco, nat, l2tp

I have problems with NAT clients connected to an AP .

1. This AP has an L2TP tunnel established to a Cisco router (7206VXR).
   The session is UP and the router can ping the IP of the client.
2. The client receives it addressing from an ISC-DHCP-Server which is
   connected at the bridge . The IP is assigned (as the GW and so on)
   correctly
3. In addition, i can ping google from the BVI interface. (I can see
   the nat translation at the router)
4. But the client can't access internet nor even the ISC-DHCP-Server
   (at the bridge) although DHCP is working fine.
5. The router can ping the client but the DHCP-Server no. The
   DHCP-Server can ping the gw (IP address of the bridge) but no the
   clients.

Here is the relevant config:

```
###interfaces
interface GigabitEthernet0/3.100

 description Bridge_DHCP

 encapsulation dot1Q 100

 no cdp enable

 bridge-group 10

 bridge-group 10 spanning-disabled

!


interface Virtual-Template10

 no ip address

 ip nat inside

 ip tcp adjust-mss 1360

 no peer default ip address

 no keepalive

 ppp mtu adaptive

 ppp mru match

 ppp authentication chap L2TP-LOGIN

 bridge-group 10

 bridge-group 10 spanning-disabled

!


interface BVI10

 ip address 10.222.0.1 255.255.255.0 secondary

 ip address 172.20.89.1 255.255.255.0

 ip nat inside

 no ip route-cache

 ip tcp adjust-mss 1360


### Bridge

bridge 10 protocol ieee

bridge 10 route ip

####NAT

ip nat pool POOL0 "Public IP" "Public IP" prefix-length 25

ip nat inside source list NATL2TP pool POOL0 overload


ip access-list extended NATL2TP
 permit ip 10.222.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

Comment: Why have you assigned two IP addresses to BVI10?

Comment: Where is the outside NAT interface?

Comment: The outside NAT is at another interface: is configured and is the one facing the Internet Router with the default gw

Comment: The 2 IP addresses are for the connectivity between the DHCP server via the primary and the secondary is the gw for the clients...once the IP address is received

Comment: That is something I have never tried. Try to switch the IP Addresses, primary and secondary and see if it helps with connectivity.

Comment: I have already tried without success.